# calculate G - Force in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to do an app like [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bmw-m-power-meter/id344494968?mt=8) . So I have searched in the Google for the G-Force calculation but didn't get any results . Please give me some guidelines .

Comment: Use the accelerometer? Where's the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the reply . I have used the accelerometer     //UIAccelerationValue finalVal =  sqrt((acceleration.x*acceleration.x)*(acceleration.y*acceleration.y)*(acceleration.z*acceleration.z));
Is this correct?

Comment: @user247 You're calculating the **product** of squares but you want the **sum**.

Answer (score 1):

That's like pseudo. Hope you got it :)

```
double gForce = sqrt (pow(Accelerometer.XAccel,2) + pow(Accelerometer.YAccel,2) + pow(Accelerometer.ZAccel,2)) / 9.81;
```

Comment: Thank you Econa , I always getting the values between 0.00 to 0.01 . Please guide me

Comment: You don't have to divide by 9.81, the API already returns G values.

Comment: You should get 1 G in normal conditions. I will write it more specific now.

Comment: You used '*' instead of '+' and be sure divided 9.81.

G-force = sqrt ((acceleration.x*acceleration.x) +(acceleration.y*acceleration.y) + (accelerati‌​on.z*acceleration.z)) / 9.81

Comment: hmmm even though I have used the + no good results

Comment: I didn't use accelerometer in iOS. But formula is true. 1 G = 9.81 m/s^2. If you want to convert m/s^2 to G, you should divide it 9.81. Try debug code and analyze the values. It's probably code mistake.